# Xamarin.iOS UITableView, how do you force a cell to update?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am using Xamarin.iOS and cannot figure out how to update a single cell.  In WPF ListView, I can just do a binding and have the cell's properties do an inotifypropertychanged and it automatically happens through the binding.  Is there some equivalent functionality in Xamarin.iOS?  It seems super cumbersome to update UITableView cells without just wiping them out and re-adding them..

What is the best way to update individual cells?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming your `UITableView` is stored in a "tableView" variable:

```
NSIndexPath[] rowsToReload = new NSIndexPath[] {
    NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(1, 0) // points to second row in the first section of the model
};
tableView.ReloadRows(rowsToReload, UITableViewCellRowAnimation.None);
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a subclass of `UICell` and bind to `INotifyPropertyChanged` there.

You can create a public property for the model object that the `UICell` is displaying.

Then update the cell's display properties when the model changes, or when a property changes...

```
public class CarCell : UITableViewCell
{
    private Car car;

    public Car Car
    {
        get { return this.car; }
        set
        {
            if (this.car == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (this.car != null)
            {
                this.car.PropertyChanged -= HandlePropertyChanged;
            }

            this.car = value;
            this.car.PropertyChanged += HandlePropertyChanged;
            SetupCell();
        }
    }

    private void HandlePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetupCell();
    }

    private void SetupCell()
    {
        this.TextLabel.Text = this.car.Title;
    }
}
```

You'll then need to create return instances of your custom cell in your `UITableViewDataSource`.

Comment: This is a very cumbersome solution, not to mention that the view (cell) is holding the data it displays. It complicates things a lot, especially considering the fact that the cell instance should be reused to display other data.

Comment: I disagree; I think it's a nice and self-contained solution that keeps all the logic for the cell encapsulated within its own class. It allows the cell to be responsible for updating itself, not the table. There's nothing stopping the cell instance being reused.