# How to use set automatically row height on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make a ListView which has a DataTemplateSelector on ItemTemplate. Basically, it looks like an expandable cell, which shows more info when the item is selected.

My code on the DataTemplateSelector:

```
protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject     container)
    {
        return ((ItemAjuda)item).Selecionado ? ExpandedTemplate : SimpleTemplate;
    }
```

and this is my code on the view:

```
<ListView
                    x:Name = "listView"
                    SeparatorVisibility = "None"
                    RowHeight = "-1"
                    HasUnevenRows="true" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Itens}" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding ItemSelecionado, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    BackgroundColor = "{StaticResource DefaultBackground}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <local:AjudaTemplateSelector/>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

It works perfectly on Android, but on IOS the cell got a strange behavior. The row height changes but it doesn't looks like an uneven row :(
Ps: I've already tried to ForceUpdateSize() on the cell, but unfortunately it doesn't change anything (maybe because of the DataTemplateSelector?)

Comment: Remove RowHeight = "-1" from listview and check yours templates, maybe here is the error.

Comment: I've tried to remove RowHeight=-1 and nothing happens. In my templates I have in both a StackLayout with VerticalOptions = FillAndExpand.

Comment: check this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/64923#Comment_64923

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407807/xamarin-ios-uitableview-how-do-you-force-a-cell-to-update
You should dig in this. I had a similar situation and used this approach.